# Failed to get the adb version: Cannot run program & Cannot allocate memory

Tags: android, eclipse, development

A little change in resources file, start giving error, and when I clean the project its delete *R.java* file and I have to restart my eclipse.

Problem is when I restart my eclipse and clean and run my project its give below error:

```
Failed to get the adb version: Cannot run program "/home/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb": java.io.IOException: error=12, Cannot allocate memory from '/home/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb' - exists=true
```

I restart the system too but same problem. Also run `chmod -R 777` but no luck.

Checked this but no help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343729/failed-to-get-adb-version-error-13-in-ubuntu-11-10

Comment: This sounds more like a problem to post to stackoverflow.com, it doesn't appear to be an Ubuntu-issue.

Comment: @user30275 But its happened with Ubuntu only before I was playing with windows there is no issue at all.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343729/failed-to-get-adb-version-error-13-in-ubuntu-11-10

Comment: @user30275 already checked but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system is 64bit?
if so, install the 32bit library

```
apt-get install ia32-libs
```